# emitting socket.io message from the client side upon connection

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have this code running from my javascript client side.

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000 + 1));

var socket = io();

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('random_number',num);
});
```

the 'random_number' never makes it to the server. A few second later I can emit messages successfully and they reach the server.... but just not the initial message upon connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('random_number',num);
});
```

The `'connection'` event is in the server API, for the client it's `'connect'`:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){
    socket.emit('random_number',num);
});
```